# Bottom overflow by 30px

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I face a problem by wrapping `TextField` with `new Expanded()`. When try to search something in `textfield` its show me bottom overflow by `30px`. Below  is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body:
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {
                setState(() {

                });
              }),
              new Flexible(
                child: new TextField(
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    onchange(value);
                  },
                  maxLines: 1,
                  autocorrect: true,
//                  decoration: const InputDecoration(helperText: "Search"),
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              _text != null ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close), onPressed: (){
              }) : new Container(),

              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: FilstList(searchtext: _text,)
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! You can use Single Child Scroll View to avoid pixel over flow.Thank You

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There are **two** solutions to this problem.

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is now ***deprecated***.

Below property of scaffold will work now.
`resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to `false` in scaffold widget.

1. Add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your Scaffold

   ```
    Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: ...)
   ```
2. Put your `FilstList(searchtext: _text,)` inside a `scrollableView` (like `SingleChildScrollView` or `ListView`)

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is now [deprecated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html). Use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` instead.

Comment: This stopped the content of my body from being displayed. The body is a `TabBarView`. Each tab view has a dynamic height as it is populated with data from a server, so the views don't have a size available to them. Placing the `TabBarView` inside a fixed size `Container` reduces UI quality.

Answer (score 13):

Use Scaffold property  "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false" 
and "SingleChildScrollView" as parent of Scaffold body:

```
      home: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Registration Page"),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: RegisterUser(),
          )),
```

this will solve issue.

Comment: omg thank you! doinght both of this like you told me worked!

Answer (score 10):

You should use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
  ... 
)
```

---

If you're having issues with overflow error, use `SingleChildScrollView` with it.

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child: YourBody()),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem and fixed it in the following way:

You can wrap it with SingleChildScrollView or with a ListView.

```
Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .50,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column( 
              ....
          )
      )
   )
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

put resizeToAvoidBottomPadding as false in Scaffold:

```
  Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

update
it is better solution:
remove Column and put instead it ListView

because if you run this app on smaller device bottom items will disappear and hide from the show screen and that will be bad for App users.

Answer (score 3):

Use of resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false in your Scaffold is the best solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

Do two way

NO1.

```
Scaffold(
 resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, )
```

The problem is when you do this body content never gone top when you select input box..

Best practice

SingleChildScrollView widget

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomScrollView` with `SliverToBoxAdapter`:

```
body: CustomScrollView( 
  slivers: [
     SliverToBoxAdapter(
         child: Form(....)
     ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Scaffold and make "resizeToAvoidBottomInset" false.

```
 Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            ........
   )
```

Comment: not working............

Answer (score -1):

Used `SigleChildScrollView`

*sample code*

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: //AppBar
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 3.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
```