# When keyboard is shown, everything is pushed up and I get a error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code:

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
        // by the _incrementCounter method above.
        //
        // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
        // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
        // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
        return new Scaffold(
            body: new Column(
          children: [
            new Container(
              color: JBTheme.colorGreenBrand,
              height: 130.0,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: new Container(
                    color: JBTheme.colorOrange,
                    constraints: new BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 270.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        new Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            new Image.asset("flags/flag_dk.png"),
                            new Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                              child: new Text("Danmark"),
                            ),
                            new Text("DKK")
                          ],
                        ),
                        new Expanded(child: new Image.asset("images/arrow.png")),
                        new Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            new Image.asset("flags/flag_us.png"),
                            new Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                              child: new Text("USA"),
                            ),
                            new Text("USD")
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
              color: JBTheme.colorGreyMedium,
              child: new Column(
                children: [
                  new Expanded(child: new Container()),
                  new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: new Card(
                      elevation: -8.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: new Container(
                          width: 200.0,
                          height: 30.0,
                          color: JBTheme.colorWhite,
                          child: new Stack(
                            children: [
                              new TextField(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
            new Container(
              height: 260.0,
              color: JBTheme.colorGreenMint,
            )
          ],
        ));
      }
    }
```

And it looks like this: [image: no keyboard]

But when I click the TextField and the keyboard opens I get this: [image]

I did not expect all of my layout to be moved up by the full keyboard height, I would like it to only move up enough so that the focused TextField is visible (and not to give a error). How can I fix this, and why is it happening?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are **two** solutions to this problem.

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is now ***deprecated***.

Below property of scaffold will work now.
`resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to `false` in scaffold widget.

1. Add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your Scaffold

   ```
    Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: ...)
   ```
2. Put your `Scaffold body` inside a scrollableView (like SingleChildScrollView or ListView)

   ```
    new Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child: //your existing body
    ...)
   ```

You can find **similar** problem and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972371/bottom-overflow-by-30px/51972954#51972954)

Answer (score 11):

This is Flutters way of showing us how many pixels of content will be hidden from users eyesight when using the keypad. Try setting [resizeToAvoidBottomPadding](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html) to false... From docs:

> Whether the body (and other floating widgets) should size themselves
>   to avoid the window's bottom padding.

```
 Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

This will avoid the resizing so you will at least avoid the dev warning being shown. But remember user will not see some content, and also this is a developer warning.

**Update on 17/10/2019**

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is now Deprecated.

Use **resizeToAvoidBottomInset** to specify if the body should resize when the keyboard appears.

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just use SingleChildScrollView content looses vertical alignment. You can also wrap the SingleChildScrollView in a Center Widget.

```
child: Center( 
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>...
```

Answer (score 0):

A full description of this error and two possible solutions can be found on Medium article available on https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660. The last one works great for me.

Comment: Please not just post a link as an answer. Once the link might be broken, someone looking for the same answer would not get any help. Please update your answer to cover the key features of the solution and provide the link only as reference.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, if at least a bit of code snippet was added here!