# Flutter rendering listView is overflowing

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have this code for a chat app that renders a series of messages. The thing is page is showing ok, but when trying to send a message rendering overflow appears. It's like my input is going all the way up instead of setting itself over my displayed keyboard.

This is my code for rendering the page

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => _messages[index],
          itemCount: _messages.length,
          //El reverse hace que vaya de abajo hacia arriba
          reverse: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        ),
      ),
      Divider(
        height: 1.0,
      ),
      Container(
        child: _buildComposer(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

And here I have my code for the input where think the mistake is

```
 Widget _buildComposer() {
return IconTheme(
  data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
  child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9.0),
    child: Row(
     // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _textController,
            onChanged: (String texto) {
              setState(() {
                _isWriting = texto.length > 0;
              });
            },
            onSubmitted: _enviarMensaje,
            decoration:
                InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Envie un mensaje!"),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            onPressed: _isWriting
                ? () => _enviarMensaje(_textController.text)
                : null,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Here are my print captures for initial rendering, after clicking inside the input to write some message

[image]

[image]

Here's my log, and it's supposed to be easy to understand the approach I should take but I'm not having any luck with it.

[image]
FYI: I have already tried this approach but did not seem to work
[StackOverflow answer on rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480051/flutter-dart-exceptions-caused-by-rendering-a-renderflex-overflowed)

I have already gone through flutter.io docs but I'm not understanding the whole listview theory. If you have some insights I would appreciate them as well so I can deeply understand how it behaves.

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` might help.. have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972371/bottom-overflow-by-30px/51972954#51972954

Comment: Dinesh, you are awesome sir, saved my day! Thanks for your quick response. If you can, please set this response as an aswer so I can give closure to this question.

Comment: the problem with resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is it doesn't push the content to top, so you won't see the last message in your screen.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` might help.. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972371/bottom-overflow-by-30px/51972954#51972954)

As @diegoveloper's comment, it will not resize which means it will not show content behind keyboard. Based on your use case you can choose option 1 or 2 in the above link