# How can i make my Scaffold widget scrollable so i would not have a "Bottom overflowed by xx Pixels" Error

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app, and i am trying to make it scrollable, because i am getting a 
"Bottom overflowed by 34 Pixels", which i am sure is caused when my widget scrolls below the apportioned height of the screen, how can i solved this issue:

[image]

i followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972371/bottom-overflow-by-30px) to solve the issue, but noting happened :

this is my code:

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Container(

      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        image: DecorationImage(
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.dstATop),
          image: AssetImage('images/space.gif'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0, left: 40.0),

            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Start",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,


                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Your",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Adventure",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 100.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new RaisedButton(

                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: Colors.blue,

                    onPressed: () => gotoSignup(),
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0,
                        horizontal: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "SIGN UP",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 30.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    onPressed: () => gotoLogin(),
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0,
                        horizontal: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "LOGIN",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by removing the height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, attribute in the first container widget